# sudo apt-get install gdb is not working on "Unable to start debugging"

Tags: c, debugging

When I try to run my code on VS code I get the error: "Unable to start debugging. The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid".
I have already tried sudo apt-get install gdb but still, get an error. I even tried to install some c debuggers on VS code but still nothing. By the way, it doesn't happen when I copy this code to a file in a different folder.

Comment: You get "an error" ?

Comment: @TimRandall yes "Unable to start debugging. The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid"

Comment: Do you get an error about installing gdb or about `miDebuggerPath` being invalid? Or both at the same time? I think if you put that exact error message about `miDebuggerPath` into the search field of StackOverflow you will find some duplicates.

Comment: @Gerhardh I get only this message that I wrote. I try to run it on VS code and it just shows me Unable to start debugging. The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You wrote 2 messages. That is why I asked.

Comment: Sorry for mistakes, I edited it.